# Google Sheets: "Dynamic Numberfetching"?

Tags: google-sheets, search, sum

I am looking for a way to search through a table for a matching a key phrase (eg. "Title"), finding all matches, and then summing up all the numbers that are in the cell directly above the matching cell.

Example:

A1='Search for "Title" and return SUM() of Numbers one Cell below

"Title" will be found in B2,C2,D2 and return the Sum of B3,C3,D3.

Any Ideas how this may be possible?

---

Maybe there is an even easier way to achieve what I want than this.
A way to expand the Table while I do not need to update the formula that adds up the variables.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(1*FILTER(B3:D3; REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B2:D2); "title")))
```

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(SUM(IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(""&D1:W; "^Last:$"); E1:W*1; ))))
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is that i want to look for the "title" in the whole table, not just a single row/column , ABC was just an example. Think more of 
B6, K6, K35, U6, U24 with the "title" and i want the sum of 
B4, K4, K33, U4, U32 (always 2 cells above)

Comment: @xCrimsonAxe can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Here is a copy of the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Yic02wsrjY7Xn0gd0EGa2Gygmm4kfHQj09ZHMiLdUcE/edit?usp=sharing

The formula is in B5 with my current workaround in place
I want to look for every occurance of "Last:" in the Table (like in M1 for example), get the neighbor-cell (N1 in this case) and sum all of them up

Comment: @xCrimsonAxe answer updated

Comment: @xCrimsonAxe see X1 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1znyMvh5AgmGt57s4Q_GDrC8Wpd0NCyFIIyTR5r9me0c/edit#gid=0 green cells in X1:BA being summed up in B13 so wherever there is exactly "Last:" in the cell it will gather the cell on right of that cell